# horizontally arrange statistical circular diagrams and place the text inside the diagram

Tags: pgf-pie, pie

I want to organize the graphics and be able to place the text inside the diagrams. If someone could help me, it would be very kind.

```
\documentclass[article,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % If you write in French
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,right=0.7in,left=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,color}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[pos={0,0},radius=2]{31/A,22/B,25/C,22/D}
    \pie[pos={6,0},radius=2]{11/E,25/K,32/F,32/G}
    \pie[pos={12,0},radius=2]{12/H,29/L,24/I,35/J}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please clarify which text and where should be in diagrams? Letters A, B, C and D together with percentages?

Comment: If you would like it to be ordered, two graphs above and one graph below, each with its respective percentage and the name right there.

Comment: What you mean with "name"? A captions?

Comment: No, that is, within the diagram there is 32% (Coca Cola) or 15% (Pepsi), etc.

Comment: Doles`\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[text=inside]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` gives result close to what you after?

Comment: And how can I place the \caption under each graph?

Comment: Enclose each in `subfigure` or in `minipage`  to which you add `\caption` command.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, I suggest you to edit your question and add more clear description what you after. Than people here will cam more easelly help you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The keys `data` and `wheel data` use `\WCperc` which gives the percentage.

The macro `\WClistcolors` refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

The wheelcharts are positioned with the key `at`.

The text below the wheelcharts is determined by the key `caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCperc{} (\WCvarB),
  radius={0}{2},
  slices style={
    fill=\WClistcolors,
    draw
  },
  start angle=0,
  WClistcolors={blue!60,cyan!60,yellow!60,orange!60},
  wheel data=\WCvarB\\\WCperc,
  wheel data style={align=center}
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(-4,6)},
  caption=name 1
]{%
  31/A,
  22/B,
  25/C,
  22/D%
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(4,6)},
  caption=name 2
]{%
  11/E,
  25/K,
  32/F,
  32/G%
}
\wheelchart[
  caption=name 3
]{%
  12/H,
  29/L,
  24/I,
  35/J%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```